# Rails: can't run app because "An error occured while installing json (1.7.7)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, bundler

Today I ran an app that on which I have been working like a half year ago and when I run the command **bundle update**, I get this error:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -I. -I/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0 -I/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DJSON_GENERATOR -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long  -fno-common -pipe -O3 -Wall -O0 -ggdb  -o generator.o -c generator.c
make: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/json-1.7.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/json-1.7.7/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing json (1.7.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Here's the relevant part from Gemfile:

```
gem "eventmachine", "~> 1.0.0"
gem "json", "~> 1.7.7"
```

I am running on Lion OS X, I found that may help to update the **Command Line Tool**, but I just updated it to the last version, but still getting this error.

Could you help me please, how to get rid of this error?

Thank you

**EDIT:** `gem install json -v '1.7.7'` returns:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -I. -I/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0 -I/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DJSON_GENERATOR -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long  -fno-common -pipe -O3 -Wall -O0 -ggdb  -o generator.o -c generator.c
make: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/json-1.7.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/json-1.7.7/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Comment: what does "gem install json -v '1.7.7'" return ?

Comment: Try `ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2` and then install again?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant - check out please updated OP, I added the statement.

Comment: @hd1 - when I try to run this command, I get the error `ln: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: Permission denied`

Comment: You need to run it as sudo, @user984621... My apologies

Comment: @hd1 - thanks, this allow me to install this gem, but now I got `Unable to load the EventMachine C extension; To use the pure-ruby reactor, require 'em/pure_ruby'` and `/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:8:in 'require': no such file to load -- rubyeventmachine (LoadError)` - which I don't understand - the **eventmachine** is added in Gemfile and installed as well.

Comment: It's a similar problem, re-run `bundle install` now. If it works, I'll copy the log of these as an answer for you to accept.

Comment: now the `bundle` command is working without errors, but when I run the app (`rails s`), I get the error as I described in the previous message.

Comment: I would also reboot.  can't hurt.

Comment: @hd1 answer worked for me, osx Mountain Lion, used `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 /usr/bin/gcc-4.2` then `gem install json -v 1.7.7` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode 4.x:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

For Xcode 5.x:

```
export CC=gcc
```